# to do list; //unable to remove list items

Tags: javascript, dom

I am unable to remove the list items from the todo list when i click on 'X',
have spent like a week on it trying different things.But none worked.
Whenever i click on the 'X' for some reason the check mark gets deleted.
If you could provide an explanation for the solution that would be great.

thanks

```
<div class="container">
          <h1>To Do</h1>
          <div class="data">
            <ul id="list">
              <li class="check"><span>&#9989</span></li>
              <li class="cross"><span>&#10062</span></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="add">
            <input id="textBox" type="text" placeholder="Add task here" />
            <button id="submit" type="submit">Add task</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
const textBox = document.querySelector('#textBox');
const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
const li = document.querySelector('li');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');
const cross = document.querySelector('.cross');

// remove an item off the list
function removeItem() {
  li.remove(list);
}
// displays text on screen
function displayText() {
  let newListItem = document.createElement('li');

  newListItem.textContent = textBox.value;

  list
    .appendChild(newListItem)
    .insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span>&#10062</span>');
  list.className = cross;
}

// clears the input after button clicked
function clearField() {
  textBox.value = '';
}

// event listener for the add button
submit.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  displayText();
  clearField();
});

// event listener for remove button
cross.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  removeItem();
});
```

Comment: There are many ways one could make this work so asking how to do it isn't really going to get you good answers. Instead, focus on a specific question. You say *But none worked*, what does that mean? Did you get errors?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at removeItem

Answer (score 0):

So you have those errors:

```
const li = document.querySelector('li');
```

this will select first li from your html.

the same as

```
const cross = document.querySelector('.cross');
```

so if other thing is correct you should be able to delete first todo list item. If you want to delete each element and create new element it's little bit more work.

Sorry this is not exact answer but you should learn more about JavaScript and DOM before you start create an appliction. Will give you some hints:

```
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');
```

this will return all li elements but not new one. so what you need is to have something called event delegation you add event listener to `ul` element, and check what you did actually click using `e.target`, you can use `e.target.classList` and check what type of class the element have or using other DOM specific fields like tag name etc. you can read about them in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

and you can get actuall li element if you use `e.target.closest('li').remove()`.